# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Cannot connect to remote server.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

How can I fix this problem ?

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ***server ip*** port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Alex/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Alex/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Alex/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Alex/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Alex/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Alex/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: What other details can you provide on this? Like what kind of system is the remote system? Is the remote system running an ssh daemon? Was the remote system up and running and reachable on the network the whole time you tried to connect to it?

Comment: use the `ssh -vvv` parameter to show more info, and edit your post please

Comment: Hi @YuJiaao please check the logs and let me know how can I fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: check this [link](http://serverfault.com/a/445059/193263)  and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer)

Answer (score 0):

I once faced this problem, i tried whatever people had suggested but after a few digins found out that my vps ssh port wasnt set the default 22, but a port 2280

hence to resolve this during ssh i had to add a port flag

```
ssh root@ipaddress -p 2280 //in my case port is 2280 yours may be different
```

also if using putty add the port omn the port text box

Answer (score 0):

Just **reboot your server** which you want to ssh. It worked for me, previously I was facing the same issue.

Comment: It was same.Thanks anyway